# Dropdownlist text change while hidden aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a drop down list with autopostback enabled.  When I change the value it updates a grideview on my webpage.  However I want to get rid of the drop down and use a textbox sort of like a search function.  I still want to keep my list though so I can compare my search string to the actual present values.  However, if I make my dropdown list invisible I cant compare values to the items in it.

Or is there a better solution?  A control that the user can't see but that I can put database values in it and compare those values with textbox text?

thanks for the help.

I am getting an error with this code:

```
    foreach (string s in DropDownList3.Items)
    { 
       //foreach gives me the error below     

       if(s == idsearch.Text)
       {
          valid = true;    
          break;
       }
    }

    if(valid == true)
    {
       GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: why do you want to compare the textbox value with dropdown values ?

Comment: dropdown list contains the values in the database that I need to search for

Comment: what makes you think you can't compare? It's just invisible, it's still in the page

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to type 'System.String'.

Comment: the issue is obvious from the question - wrong casting

Answer (score 0):

error is due to casting ListItem to string. Do as :

```
foreach (ListItem s in DropDownList3.Items)
{
    if(s.Text== idsearch.Text){


       valid = true;

       break;
    }
}
```

Or you can find item by Text or Value using `DropDownList.Items.FindByText` or `DropDownList.Items.FindByValue` methods.

```
var searchResult = DropDownList1.Items.FindByText(idsearch.Text);

bool valid = searchResult != null;
```

Answer (score 0):

DropDownList3.Items return a System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem and not List. You should do this

```
  foreach (ListItem item in DropDownList3.Items)
  { //foreach gives me the error below

    if(item.Text == idsearch.Text)
    {

      valid = true;

      break;
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a variable in your server side code to store the values in the dropdownlist. So for example..

```
String [] comparedValues = new String[4] {"value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"};
```

and then..

```
if (comparedValues.Contains(myTextBox.Text))
{
    // Do Something...
}
```